# Function returns None unexpectedly

Tags: python

Ok. So I finished this piece of code I have been working on, but I have a major problem. I doesn't return correctly.

```
if is_word(wordlist, decodedText):
        print 'entered if statement'
        print answer
        return answer
```

this is the piece of code that isn't working. The rest of the program isn't necessary. The line about entering the if statement was just a debug, so I would actually know that it did enter. The next print statement was to make sure that my variable answer actually was assigned to something, like it was elsewhere in the program.
Now, this is what the code is giving me:

`entered if statement
[(0, -6), (3, -18), (12, -16)]
None`

I also tried using type(answer) to make sure that I didn't have some weird bug I wasn't seeing, but it was just saying it was a list.

So, why am I getting a None return??

```
answer = []
def find_best_shifts_rec(wordlist, text, start):
    """
    Given a scrambled string and a starting position from which
    to decode, returns a shift key that will decode the text to
    words in wordlist, or None if there is no such key.

    Hint: You will find this function much easier to implement
    if you use recursion.

    wordlist: list of words
    text: scambled text to try to find the words for
    start: where to start looking at shifts
    returns: list of tuples.  each tuple is (position in text, amount of shift)
    """
    global answer
    for shift in range(27):
        decodedText = apply_shift(text[start:], -shift)
        if is_word(wordlist, decodedText):
            print 'entered if statement'
            print answer
            return(answer)
        split = decodedText.split()
        if is_word(wordlist,split[0]) == True:
            answer.append((start, -shift))
            find_best_shifts_rec(wordlist, decodedText, (start+(len(split[0])+1)))
            break

print find_best_shifts_rec(wordlist, "JufYkaolfapxQdrnzmasmRyrpfdvpmEurrb?", 0)
```

This is the rest of my function. Let me know if there is something else you need to see.

Comment: The rest of the program is absolutely necessary, as what you've posted is not sufficient to debug your problem.

Comment: How are you capturing and printing the return value?

Comment: I'm just using answer.append((0, -6)), for the first one.

Comment: But how would that explain why print answer gives me the correct list of tuples?

Comment: I'm certain that if it prints that, the list is returned, and None isn't. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: In my research on unexpected None returns, I found that people have had issues with imports. I have random and string imported, and both are necessary to the functionality of the program.

Comment: Err, you are modifying and returning a global from a recursive function, and this is not significant for getting the full picture?  What else aren't you telling us?

Comment: I originally had the variable answer declared within the function, but for some reason it introduced a little bug where after each append, it would delete the previously appended tuple. the global variable is nothing but answer = []

Comment: you need to return your recursive case ...

Comment: I'm so confused. I just don't understand what the difference between what it prints and what it returns.

Comment: it returns it to your recursive call ... but you dont return that so the original call returns none ...

Comment: Ohhh ok I guess that makes sense...huh. That didn't really occur to me. I guess I don't have as firm of a grasp on recursion as I thought I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was you were not returning your recursive result ....

```
if is_word(wordlist,split[0]) == True:
        answer.append((start, -shift))
        return find_best_shifts_rec(wordlist, decodedText, (start+(len(split[0])+1)))
```

Comment: theres the problem ... you were not returning your recursive case ... I suspect there are still paths through your code that will return none (if both if statements are false at any point)

Comment: This is it. The code works now. I don't really completely understand, but at least it outputs what it is supposed to now. Thank you!